# MySQLSyntaxErrorException when trying to select from sqoop

Tags: mysql, sqoop

Our job runs following SQLs for report generation. This one succeeds.

```
SELECT sale_alerts_id,
       email,
       first_name,
       last_name,
       address_1,
       address_2,
       apt_for_suite,
       city,
       state,
       zip_code,
       phone,
       cast(capture_tmst as char),
       capture_id,
       associate_id,
       store_nbr,
       cast(last_updated_tmst as char),
       subscribed_ind,
       cookie_id  
FROM account.est_sale_alerts 
WHERE last_updated_tmst>"2018-09-13 12:14:58" 
  AND last_updated_tmst <= "2018-09-14 00:30:45:502767" 
  AND 1=1;
```

This one fails with error:

```
SELECT sale_alerts_id,
       email,
       first_name,
       last_name,
       address_1,
       address_2,
       apt_for_suite,
       city,
       state,
       zip_code,
       phone,
       cast(capture_tmst as char),
       capture_id,
       associate_id,
       store_nbr,
       cast(last_updated_tmst as char),
       subscribed_ind,
       cookie_id 
FROM account.est_sale_alerts 
WHERE last_updated_tmst>"2018-09-16 00:30:45" 
  AND last_updated_tmst <= "2018-09-16 12:30:46:462785"
  and 1=1;
```

Error is:

> 19-09-2018 15:30:17 CDT sale-alerts-pii-l1 INFO - Caused by:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''76?????'' )'
>   at line 1

Why is second query giving error?

P.S: If there are any editing mistakes, I can correct it. Am new to this forum.

Comment: Like I have edited your second query, please go ahead and edit your first query also, so that it is readable without scrolling horizontally

Comment: I have a feeling the latter query is not actually the query being run, as it contains no reference to 76?????.

Comment: I edited the code. Also, both run fine by hand within mysql

Comment: Can you put the exact sqoop command that you're trying to run in both the cases?